# Ability to conditionally choose what row to select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

This is mostly to see if I can find a way to work around this limitation.

Let's say I have the following query:

```
var query = (from a in db.Table
             where a.CustomFieldId == FieldID && a.ListingId == listingID
             select a.SomeTypeValue);
```

The table I am querying is set for custom fields that may vary in type, so it has several columns but only uses the appropriate column to store the value based on the field's selected type.

The table looks somewhat like this:

[image]

I want to be able to choose which column I select without rewriting the whole query. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be rewrited to use "Method Call LINQ":

```
db.Table
  .Where(a => a.CustomFieldId == FieldID && a.ListingId == listingID)
  .Select(x => x.SomeType);
```

You may split query into Where and Select parts then:

```
var result = whereQuery.Select(x => x.BoolValue);
```

or

```
var result = whereQuery.Select(x => x.IntValue);
```

You may even encapsulate that logic into method:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>() {
  var query = db.Table
      .Where(a => a.CustomFieldId == FieldID && a.ListingId == listingID);

  if (typeof(T)==typeof(bool)) {
    return query.Select(x => x.BoolColumn);
  }
  else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) {
    return query.Select(x => x.IntColumn);
  }
  // other types here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this shows the limitation of query syntax. I tried this with query syntax but it gave some compile errors.